# What is this modified Runge-Kutta method and what error estimates exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

In RK methods you are given a (small) time increment $h>0$, then you compute an approximate solution $(y_n)_n$ of an (autonomous, say) ODE $y'=X(y)$ by computing a well-chosen linear combination of terms $X(y_n+h k_j)$ that yields $y_{n+1}$. The error is $O(h^\mathrm{order})$, and effective bounds can be obtained when enough regularity is imposed on $X$.

I'm wondering what happens when you don't fix $h$ and take it to be at each step $n$  of the form $$h:=\frac{h_0}{||X(y_n)||}$$ or $h:=\frac{h_0}{\max(||X(y_n)||,1)}$, for given $h_0>0$. This is a kind of "adaptative" method (it somehow adapts the time increment to the size of $X$), that seems to give a pretty good  (accuracy)/(computation time) ratio, at least visually.

Is it known/named/studied? How would I go finding explicit error estimates?

If that helps (though I doubt it) I'm mainly interested when $y\in\mathbb C$ and $X$ is holomorphic/polynomial.

Comment: This arranges that each step covers about the same arc length. But it still has short steps for constant vector fields that have linear solutions and thus would give exact results with larger steps. Also, constant-length vector fields can still rapidly rotate, which this method also does not see. So in some cases like 1- or 2-body orbital simulations, this gives better result than the unmodified fixed-step method, but try out a 3-body simulation and observe the energy.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: thanks for the input. In that case, the version with $\max(||X(y_n)||,1)$ should give no worse results (that's the one that I use, but somehow I feel the error study would be less easy). Would you have any pointer in the literature (a method name, a book) ?

Comment: No, I do not have ready references for that. I also think that not much will exist, perhaps some remarks in older engineering-oriented textbooks. For all other purposes, proper variable step methods of low order are also easy to implement and explore. The paper https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Efeldman/math/vble.pdf has some of such exploration of embedded methods, Fehlberg wrote a paper around 1970 on low-order method where he also introduces some low-order FSAL methods. With RK4 or any other method one can also use step-doubling for error estimates and step-size control.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: OK, thank you again for your time. I'll look at the above reference. I understand that this approach is kind of naive and that better ones exist, I was mainly asking out of curiosity since it seems a rather natural simple modification to perform.

Comment: I used this in the 1990s to follow a solution into a singularity. Today it is in some kind on no-mans land. If you want to explore ODE solutions, you use an established solver. If you want to learn about the numerical methods, you use examples that are interesting but not that interesting. One may still be interested in speed regulation, but then one would apply the factor in the ODE function, not in the solver. And the better modification is to apply a factor or divisor that leaves the whole expression asymptotically linear.